# How to rerun a test and keep history on TFS?

Tags: testing, tfs, azure-devops, alm

everyone.

I was reading [this page](http://sxp.microsoft.com/feeds/msdntn/TFS) that describes how to run tests in Team Foundation Service. But the page doesn't describe what happens to a test that was ran again. How to keep history of the times that the test was ran? Maybe using the "Copy Test" feature?

Can someone explain better the proccess of testing in Team Foundation Service?

Thank you guys very much.